# Trying to concatenate a String to a MutableLiveData<String> with postValue(), but it's missing some pieces

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines, android-mvvm

#### Problem

I'm trying to implement a simple "log" view with a `TextView` and a `String` using a `ViewModel`.

The idea that came to my mind was to simply concatenate text to `LiveData<String>` using `setValue()`, but I need the app to work without blocking the UI.
So I put the code inside a coroutine, but `setValue()` can only be called from the main thread.
I tried with `postValue()`, but if called fast it doesn't add the text.

I came up with a solution: using `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)`, but I think it's hacky and not the way to go.

Is there another way to write this "better"?

#### Goal

"a" + "b" + "c" = "abc"

#### Using `postValue()`

Result: "a" + "b" + "c" = "ac"

As you can see from the screenshot, it's missing some cycles.

```kotlin
private val _data = MutableLiveData<String>()
val data: LiveData<String> = _data

init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        _data.value = "Example data"
    }
}

fun longTask() {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
        // Long task running in the background
        for (i in 0..200000) {
            // Need to use postValue() because setValue() cannot be called from here
            _data.postValue("${_data.value} - $i")
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot for postValue result]

#### Using `setValue()`

Result: "a" + "b" + "c" = "abc"

```kotlin
private val _data = MutableLiveData<String>()
val data: LiveData<String> = _data

init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        _data.value = "Example data"
    }
}

fun longTask() {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
        // Long task running in the background
        for (i in 0..200000) {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                _data.value = "${_data.value} - $i"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot for setValue result]

---

EDIT: Added pictures.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do. The LiveData only updates its observers on the main thread. If you update its value multiple times on a background thread before it has a chance to notify listeners on the Main thread, only the most recent value will be passed to observers. 200000 isn't even a very big number. This will likely run through the for loop so fast that the LiveData will only ever broadcast the very last number to its observers. Is this placeholder code for something that is actually blocking the thread for a while?

Comment: Yes, it is placeholder code. I don't think the problem is the observers not updating, but the LiveData not changing the value fast enough. I'm trying to do `"a" + "b" + "c"`, but in this case is too fast for `postValue()` to update it, so when it tries to concatenate the next character, `_data.value` is still `"a"` and not `"ab"`.